# Getting crazy results in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am having to write a simple program in assembly that takes an N number inputs as ints, and finds the average of them all added together. As the tittle suggests, I am getting crazy numbers for answers.

Here is the code that I have written.

```
%include "along32.inc"

section .data

intA dq 0; Holds the input value
total dq 0; Holds the sum of the entered values
average dq 0; Holds the average of the values entered
counter dq 0; Keeps up with how many values are entered

pleasentry db "Hello!, I will find the average of the numbers you enter.", 0
instruction db "Enter a value. Once you have entered all your values, enter             a 0.", 0
inPut db "Please enter a value.", 0
theAverage db "The average is: ", 0



section .text
    global _start

_start:

;Pleasentry
    mov edx, pleasentry
    call WriteString
    call Crlf

;Instructions
    mov edx, instruction
    call WriteString
    call Crlf
    jmp again

;Meat of the program
again:
    mov edx, inPut
    call WriteString
    call ReadInt
    mov [intA], eax
    cmp eax, 0
    je final
    jne next

;Adds the input to the total and increments the counter by 1
next:
    mov ebx, total
    add eax, ebx
    mov [total], eax
    mov ecx, counter
    inc ecx
    mov [counter], ecx
    jmp again

;Does the math and exits the program
final:
    mov eax, total
    call WriteInt
    mov ebx, counter
    call WriteInt
    cdq
    idiv ebx
    mov [average], eax
    mov edx, theAverage
    call WriteString
    call WriteInt
    jmp exit

exit:
    mov eax, 01h
    mov ebx, 0h

    int 80h
```

When I enter 2 three times I get 134520876 for the total and the counter, and 0 for the average. I can't figure out what is going wrong. I'm pretty sure it's something to do with the registers, and how I am moving things in and out of them. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `mov ebx, total` should be `mov ebx, [total]`. Also in other places. Learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Wow, that fixed my problem. Thanks!